# Manually added select options cause observable value to be cleared

Tags: knockout.js

In scenarios where options are manually added to a bound select element, the original value of the observable is lost after applyBindings. The value is not lost if options are added using the options binding. I have demonstrated the effect here: http://jsfiddle.net/nigelw/CkyjC

**Edit:** *Note that I am talking about initial creation/binding of the select - not later adding options to an existing select.*

Is there a reason for this?

Sample code:

```
<!-- In this test, select options are added manually within a
            foreach construct. Select works as expected, but initial
            value of observable is cleared. -->
<select data-bind="value: ChoiceA">
    <!-- ko foreach: Choices -->
    <option data-bind="text: Name, value: Id"></option>
    <!-- /ko -->
</select>

<p>ChoiceA = [<span data-bind="text: ChoiceA"></span>]</p>

<!-- In this test, select options are added using options binding.
        Select works as expected and initial value of observable is kept. -->
<select data-bind="options: Choices, optionsText: 'Name', optionsValue: 'Id', value: ChoiceB"></select>

<p>ChoiceB = [<span data-bind="text: ChoiceB"></span>]</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var model = {
        // Store the selection here. Initialised to 3. This selects
        // the correct option, but the value then disappears until a
        // new selection is made.
        "ChoiceA": ko.observable(3),

        // Store the selection here. Initialised to 3. This selects
        // the correct option, and the value stays as expected.
        "ChoiceB": ko.observable(3),

        // The options
        "Choices": ko.observableArray([
            { Id: 1, Name: "Option1" },
            { Id: 2, Name: "Option2" },
            { Id: 3, Name: "Option3" }])
    };

    ko.applyBindings(model);
</script>
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem, and can confirm that the initial value is empty when manually adding the options. The reason why I have to add them manually is because I need to bind to a list and add a different value (not in the list) to the options.

Answer (score 0):

I Don't understand the problem here.  If you look at how knockout binds the examples you are showing are exactly correct..  If you want to add an Option just use choices.push(newOption);

If your setting a value and then overriding it you will get a problem, but that is exactly how knockout is supposed to work.

If you wanted to set a value in a different manner (not using the Id) then you can do that by passing an object into the ChoiceA observable instead of an Id.  In your code example you aren't specifying that the optionValue should be an I'd but you pass an Id not the selected observable (ChoiceA) and you are breaking the binding anyway.

An example would be if you changed the code to -

```
var ChoiceA = ko.observable(choices()[0]);
```

It will select an option

Comment: I'm talking about the initial binding of the select object here. If you look at the jsfiddle example (without changing any selections) you'll see that two seemingly identical methods of building the select behave in different ways. In my real case, I wanted to bind the observable value to another object as well as the select (effectively showing the current selection somewhere else). That was fine once a new selection was made, but original value always shown as blank - even though correct option in select was picked.

Comment: It doesn't matter, you can't bind it to an object, pass an integer, and expect Knockout to translate it without setting an optionsValue

Comment: It was my understanding that I was doing effectively the same thing in both examples. I modified the code in jsfiddle, trying both setting ChoiceA to an item of Choices and adding optionsText/optionsValue to the select binding. Neither made any difference.

Comment: Brotha, its not.  In the first example you are binding the options to JavaScript objects with multiple properties.  Then you are giving the selected option a value that is an integer.  On the apply bindings, knockout realizes that the integer doesn't match any objects in the options binding.

Comment: I can see what you're saying, but it doesn't really solve the problem. I updated the code (http://jsfiddle.net/nigelw/CkyjC/9) so that both ChoiceA and ChoiceB are initialised with objects from Choices. Despite this, after binding both values are overwritten - ChoiceA as a string (matches normal option value type), ChoiceB as a number (matches Id type in Choices object). Doing it this way failed to select the correct option in both examples. Is what I have done what you're suggesting??

Comment: It does solve the problem.  It is called the learners paradox - you don't know what you don't yet know.  http://jsfiddle.net/CkyjC/11/  You have to specify what the value type is if you want to pass it in like in the fiddle I just included

Comment: I thought you had it there for a minute. But you've effectively made the first example the same as the second one. I know the second method works, I'm trying to figure out why the first one doesn't. To answer the question, the select must be constructed using option elements, not using the 'options' binding on the select.

Comment: But why would you do that?  Why not just create a computed ot something?

Comment: Well, in one particular case I was grouping options and hiding options based on conditions. I ended up encapsulating all of that in a custom binding. The point is that it _should_ have worked the other way too. It does work once the selection is changed. But the original value is lost as described.

Answer (score -1):

Used to have issues and weird behavior myself manually binding select lists like this. Just stick to using the options binding.

Comment: Well, yes, I've had to write a custom binding handler to do what I was doing before to get it to work. It seems strange though. I've pretty much put it down to being a bug, but wanted to make sure there wasn't something silly that I had missed.

Comment: There are notes at the bottom of the api documentation for the options binding. Without digging through the source they seem to suggest that there is some consideration given selected values when options are bound.

Comment: To whoever downvoted this answer: While not giving a solution, it did at least confirm that I am not the only one who has experienced issues with this. While I wouldn't vote this answer as particularly useful, I wouldn't necessarily call it unuseful either.  :/